# Remove the duplicate from a String Using Pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
char *removedps(char *x)
{
    int Ar[256] = {0};
    int ip=0;
    int op=0;
    char temp;
    while(*(x+ip))
    {
       temp  = (*(x+ip));
       if (!Ar[temp])  {
         Ar[temp] = 1;
         *(x+ip) = *(x+op);
         op++;
       }
       ip++;
       *(x+op) = '\0';
    }
  return x;
}

int main()
{
  char lo[] = "0001";
  printf("%s",removedps(lo));    
}
```

My code is not working 
I have tried hard to see the error 
All I GET IS the first character .
My idea is simple
make an array of 256 places
insert Zero into them 
Then insert 1 for each character inside the string (on that position of the array)

Comment: Do they have to be consecutive ?

Comment: not necessary :they can be anywhere :the re can be anywhere

Answer (score 1):

because  `*(x+op) = '\0';`

is always run every iteration of the loop.

I'd probablly do it more like this ( using your method, which I probablly wouldn't use personally)

```
char *removedps(char *x)
{
    int Ar[256] = {0};
    char* start = x;
    while(*x)
    {       
        if (Ar[*x])   
        {  // remove the repeated character 
           memmove(x, x+1, strlen(x));
        }   
        else
        {
            Ar[*x] = 1;
            x++;
        }       
    }
    return start;
}
```

also, I'd name it remove_duplicate_chars  or something,  not a fan of cryptic abbreviations.

Comment: I have removed and replaced the statement :Still facing problems

Comment: `int Ar[256] = {0};` is neater and more concise than using `memset` I think, chances are the `= {0}` may end up being a call to `memset` anyway, but I think it looks nicer.

Answer (score 1):

your assignment looks to be the error here.

op is "out postiion", ip is "in position"

so it should be

`*(x+op) = *(x+ip);`

not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the loop, you do `*(x+op)='\0';`, and then, in the next iteration, you do `*(x+ip)=*(x+op);`, so from the 2sd iteration, you put there 0.

try do something like:

```
for (op=ip=0;x[ip];ip++) {
 if (!Ar[x[ip]]++) x[op++]=x[ip];
}
x[op]=0;
```